# There is an error in XML document when deserializing(C#)

Tags: c#, xml

I have the following xml:

[XML](https://pastebin.com/2kii64vT)

I have the following C# class

[C# GlobalClass](https://pastebin.com/VrfvtgwU)

I am trying to convert the xml content into C# custom object like that:

```
string xmlFilePath = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.ToString() + "/Settings4/settings.xml";
XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(GlobalClass));
TextReader textReader = new StreamReader(xmlFilePath);
GlobalClass globalVariables;
globalVariables = (GlobalClass)deserializer.Deserialize(textReader);
textReader.Close();
```

But I get

```
There is an error in XML document
```

on the line of code

```
globalVariables = (GlobalClass)deserializer.Deserialize(textReader);
```

I make GlobalClass inherit from Application because I want GlobalClass to be global that is to say I want to use its properties throughout all activities. What I'm doing wrong to recieve that error?

Comment: Try serializing an object of type `GlobalClass` to a file and see the result. It will have different structure than the the file you have provided.

Comment: Why serialize? I only need to get the values of the XML file and map them to the c# object.

Comment: You can ask Visual studio to create a class based on Xml, or use online generator if you don't have this option : http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: can be a dupe :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364253/how-to-deserialize-xml-document

Answer (score 0):

In your class put something like this `[Serializable, XmlRoot("YourRoot")]`
When you work with **deserialization** it might not found.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlrootattribute.elementname%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> The name of the XML root element that is generated and recognized in
>   an XML-document instance. The default is the name of the serialized
>   class.

Comment: What do I have to put in "YourRoot" in my case?

Comment: It worked but all property values in C# object are null or false if they are of type bool.